# Pagination used with limit-offset having problem in page specific validation rule evaluation

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, pagination

I'm using a pagination with soql limit-offset to display a list of records in a pageblocktable. there is a custom validation rule defined, if same product name is used twice it will get restricted. But this restriction applies only for the set of records within the current selected page not the whole recordset across all pages. Can anyone help me, what is the best approach to implement such validation rule, that will be applicable to whole set of records. Here is my code :

```
public class inline{
    public List<Competitor_Mapping__c> records=new List<Competitor_Mapping__c>();
    public List<Competitor_Mapping__c>lstAcct1  = new List<Competitor_Mapping__c>();
    public integer index = 0;
    public integer blockSize = 2;
    public integer totalRecs=[select count() from Competitor_Mapping__c where Account__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    public List<Competitor_Mapping__c> getrecords()
    {
        List<Competitor_Mapping__c> newRecords = new List<Competitor_Mapping__c>();
        for (Competitor_Mapping__c r : records) {
            if (r.Id == null) {
                newRecords.add(r);
            }
        }
        records= [select id,Competitor_Product__c,January__c,February__c,March__c,April__c,May__c,June__c,July__c,August__c,September__c,October__c,November__c,December__c from Competitor_Mapping__c where Account__c =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') limit : blocksize Offset :index];
        for (Competitor_Mapping__c r : newRecords)
        {records.add(0,r);}
        return records;
    }

    public inline(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {  
        records= [select id,Competitor_Product__c from Competitor_Mapping__c where Account__c =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') order by Competitor_Product__c asc];
    } 
    public Pagereference Save()
    {
        Boolean okayToAdd = true;
        Set<String>dupe_chk= new Set<String>();
        dupe_chk.clear();
        lstAcct1.clear();

        for(Integer j = 0;j<records.size();j++)
        { 
            if(!dupe_chk.contains(records[j].Competitor_Product__c))
            {   
                dupe_chk.add(records[j].Competitor_Product__c);
            }
            else
            {  
                okayToAdd = false;
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'This Competitor Product Sales is already existing. Please Select another Product !'));
                continue;
            }

            if(okayToAdd)
            {
                lstAcct1.add(records[j]);
            }

        }

        UpSert lstAcct1;

        return null;
    }

    public void AddMore()
    {

        Competitor_Mapping__c newRec=new Competitor_Mapping__c (Account__c =Acc_Id);
        records.add(newRec);
    }
    public void beginning()
    {
        index = 0;        
    }
    public void previous()
    {
        index = index - blockSize;
    }
    public void next()
    {
        index = index + blockSize;
    }
    public void end()
    {
        index = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,blockSize);
    }        
    public boolean getprev()
    {
        if(index == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }  
    public boolean getnxt()
    {
        if((index + blockSize) > totalRecs)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } 
}
```

page code :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="inline"  id="thePage"> 
    <apex:form id="theForm"> 
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock"  > 
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom" > 
                <apex:commandButton value="<<" rerender="thePageBlock" action="{!beginning}"  disabled="{!prev}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="<" rerender="thePageBlock" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value=">" rerender="thePageBlock" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value=">>" rerender="thePageBlock" action="{!end}" disabled="{!nxt}"/> 

            </apex:pageblockButtons>          
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" title="Competitor Sales" collapsible="true">
                <!--apex:actionFunction name="saveComplexity" action="{!save}" rerender="thePageBlock"/-->
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"  id="saveButton"  style="display:none" />

                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel" id="cancelButton" reRender="thePageBlock" style="display: none;" />

                <!--apex:commandLink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;"  id="saveButton" /-->
                <!--apex:commandButton action="{!calledit}" value="edit" id="editButton" rendered="{!records.size>0}"/-->
                <!--apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton"  reRender="thePageBlock"  style="display: none;" rendered="{!records.size>0}"/-->
                <apex:commandButton value="Add New" action="{!AddMore}" id="AddMoreButton"    />        

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="k" id="thePageBlockTable" rendered="{!records.size>0}" headerClass="headerStyle"  columnsWidth="60%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%,20%"> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Competitor Product" style="border:1px solid;border-color:lightgray; font-size:13px;">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!k.Competitor_Product__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" style="border-left:5px solid;border-left-color:red;" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductNames}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:column> 
                </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to reduce this code to just the minimum amount needed to illustrate your issue? This is a lot of code to go through. Comments, etc, that aren't necessary just create clutter that we then have to sort through.

Comment: yes sure @sfdcfox ..i'm editing the code

Comment: That's much better. I'll take a peek, or perhaps someone will beat me to it.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox , can you please look into this? thanks